# Qt-Cretor + CMake insists on using MSVC when I want to use MinGW

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

I am trying to build a CMake project with MinGW. I have installed MinGW 8.1 through the Qt installer. The CMakeList is unchanged from how Qt Creator created it when creating the project.

When running CMake, I can see how Qt Creator passes the compiler and linker's paths to CMake and how CMake completely ignores them.

```
Führe C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -S [snip] -B [snip] "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:String=Debug" "-DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:STRING=C:/Qt/5.15.1/mingw81_64/bin/qmake.exe" "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING=C:/Qt/5.15.1/mingw81_64" "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING=C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/bin/gcc.exe" "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/bin/g++.exe" in [snip] aus.
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.19041.
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.24.28314.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE
    CMAKE_C_COMPILER
    QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE
```

Here I am using a system install of CMake, but the output is unchanged when using the CMake installed with Qt Creator. The CMake generator for the selected kit is set to MinGW Makefiles in the Qt Creator settings. Running CMake manually, without Qt Creator, allows me to configure the project. (although it still doesn't compile because of a linker error, that I expect to be independent of this problem)

Comment: Maybe this helps: close QtCreator, delete QtCreator's CMakeLists.txt.user, also the build folder. Open the project again and select the desired kit. It seems there is a caching issue.

Comment: @bzs You were right. I had removed the build directory multiple times before, as this usually solves caching issues. Only when removing the CMakeLists.txt.user file as well was the issue solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a caching issue. The caching is done by CMake (CMakeCache.txt) and by QtCreator (CMakeLists.txt.user) itself.

Maybe this helps:

1. Close QtCreator (by closing QtCreator the CMakeLists.txt.user file is saved or generated if the file don't exist)
2. delete QtCreator's CMakeLists.txt.user
3. the build folder
4. Open the project again and select the desired kit.